# Is there a Delegation Token example of spark on k8s by using secrets?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, hdfs, kerberos

We are using spark on k8s with a kerberized HDFS. I saw [there are several ways to enable kerberos](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#kerberos) and one of them is by using delegation token with pre-populated secrets within the namespace. But I can hardly find a complete example.

How do I create a delegation token in HDFS side then populate it into secret in k8s ?

any answer or reference is greatly apprecaited

Comment: Refer this [document](https://blog.cloudera.com/hadoop-delegation-tokens-explained/) may be helpful to you